# Equivalente de "CLng()" y "Mod" en ésta linea de código de VB.NET en C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms, vb6

Estoy mudando código de VB6 a C#, y tengo ésta línea de código que no puedo mudar debido a que no encuentro ni equivalentes ni formas de obtener lo que debería con `CLng()` y `Mod`. La función `CLng()` realiza un redondeo de fracciones que no logro llevar a cabo. En cuanto a `Mod` realiza una división y devuelve sólo el resto.

Buscando en diferentes página encontré que el equivalente de `CLng()` sería `long<expresión>` o lo que sería lo mismo `Convert.ToInt64(expresión)`, pero lamentablemente no me funciona con el código que tengo ya que trunca el número, no lo redondea.

En relación a `Mod`, encontré que el equivalente es `%` (porcentaje), aunque ni se acercó a lo que debo obtener. Luego encontré ésto: `Resultado = Math.DivRem(Divisor, Dividendo, out Resto);` donde seguramente se obtiene lo que necesito, pero en el código que tengo es imposible y ahora van a ver por qué.

LINEA DE CÓDIGO A EVALUAR:

```
*VB6 -> lChar = CLng("&H" & Mid(sMD5, (lCount * 2) - 1, 2)) Mod 32

*VB.NET -> lChar = CLng("&H" & Mid(sMD5, (lCount * 2) - 1, 2)) Mod 32
```

DETALLE IMPORTANTE: la variable `sMD5` es de tipo `string` de tipo algoritmo `MD5`, por lo que es imposible trabajarla en C# como lo propone esa línea de código de VB6.

Espero la ayuda correspondiente. Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Por un lado, hablas de C#, pero luego en tu código hablas de vb.net. Es lo uno o lo otro? Por otro, sería interesante que pusieras un ejemplo del resultado en vb6.

Comment: También necesitamos saber de que tipo es la variable `lChar`, para saber que tipo de resultado necesitas.

Comment: ¿Tendrás un ejemplo de que valores entran para `sMD5`, `lCount` y que valor esperarías obtener?

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda. La variable lChar es de tipo long @Pikoh.

Comment: La variable sMD5 entra con "ff91e01fa185be3a4bf4b147ec24c4" por ejemplo. Y lCount es de tipo long y comienza en 1 para ir incrementándose de uno en uno, ya que es usada en un for. @DiegoTorres

Comment: Prueba con algo asi: `lChar = Convert.ToInt64(sMD5.SubString((lCount * 2)-2,2), 16) % 32;`

Comment: El tema es que sMD5 es de tipo string y lChar es de tipo long. Tengo que hacer % 32 de un string. Por lo que debería pasar sMD5 a int, lo que no se puede debido a que viene cargada con números y letras. Alguna otra solución?.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt64`,poniendo como segundo parametro la base (16 en este caso), ya hace lo que pides. Has probado el código que te he puesto? Te da algun error?

Comment: [Aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mnkGUJ) tienes un fiddle con un ejemplo. Ten en cuenta que lCount debe ser int, no long, ya que `Substring` espera un entero como parametro.

Comment: Ya me di cuenta lo de la base 16 como segundo parámetro de `Convert.ToInt64` y lo de `lCount` como `int`. Ya no me tira error, me devuelve un valor que tengo que corroborar que sea correcto ejecutando el código del Visual 6. Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Estaré avisando si funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Por suerte ya pude hacerlo funcionar. Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda y por los consejos. Los iré tomando en cuenta para futuras preguntas, respuestas, comentarios, etc. Saludos.